# MediaBrowserCompat's "connect()" method always return to onConnectonFailed() on Oreo, but works fine on Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, android-music-player, mediabrowserservicecompat, mediabrowser

MediaBrowserCompat's "connect()" method always return to onConnectonFailed() on Android Oreo but works fine on Marshmallow

My "MediaActivity" onCreate() contains

```
mediaBrowserCompat = new MediaBrowserCompat(this, new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), MediaService.class),
                connectionCallback,getIntent().getExtras());
mediaBrowserCompat.connect();
```

Support Library used is "com.android.support:support-v13:28.0.0-alpha3"
Tested on 
Oreo - Samsung S8 Edge
Marshmallow - Redmi 3s prime

Comment: Why are you using an alpha version of the support library?

Comment: @NickShvelidze I tried using 27.0.0 as well earlier but  it didn't work with that either so I tried using latest version i.e 28.0.0- alpha